# SLURM: Specify number of cores per node

Tags: nodes, cpu, slurm

Using Slurm, it's possible to request a certain amount of cores on a node. For instance, `#SBATCH -N 1 -n 8` requests 8 cores on one node. Following this logic, `#SBATCH -N 10 -n 16` requests 16 cores divided over 10 compute nodes (16 cores in total). I can also specify which nodes should be used, e.g. `#SBATCH -N 2 -n 4 -w node2, node3` will request 4 cores on the nodes named `node2` and `node3`.

So far, so good. But I would like to

1. Specify the nodes to use (`-w` flag)
2. And specify how many cores should be requested on every node

For the second point, I cannot use the `-n` flag, as it does not allow to allocate the requested cores on specific nodes. However, in my case specifying the cores per node is necessary, as a unlucky distribution of the processes on one node (e.g. 20 cpu's on node2 instead of 10 cpu's on each node2 and node3) would consume too much memory on the node and the processes would eventually break.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can ask for a specific memory per CPU, so you will have that memory guaranteed despite the core distribution.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with e.g. ```#SBATCH --mem=64G```. However, it would still like to specify the cores per node as it often happens that the processes are distributed very unequally over the nodes which is eventually ineffective

Comment: Why is it inneffective? Every process have its own resources and should not affect the execution of others.

Comment: If processes consume a lot of memory, they'll slow down other processes. Furthermore, if I run 8 processes on a 16 core node consuming around 80% of the memory of that node, the risk of a memory error is greater than running 4 processes on two 16 core nodes consuming 40% of each of the nodes. I'm not the only person using our cluster, other users may need memory too.

Comment: All users ask the memory they need. If they consume more than requested, they are killed. There can not be shortage of memory in this configuration. This is the job of a resource manager like SLURM. If you consume 80% of the memory of the node, there's plento of extra space for the OS. Your jobs won't be disturbed by any other user or job because they have their own share of memory. If 80% is not enough for your jobs, ask for more, then SLURM won't allocate 8 CPUs in the same node due to lack of memory.